# Karate: Logging of POST form parameters

Tags: karate

After upgrade from 0.9.6 to 1.0.0 I noticed that the logging of the POST requests seems changed, and the params present as form parameters are not visible in the logs.

Is there a way to activate them again? It is very hard to debug without them.

1.0.0

```
    # 1 > POST https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
    # 1 > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    # 1 > Content-Length: 9
    # 1 > Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
    # 1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
    # 1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.7)
    # 1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

0.9.6

```
    # logging will show something like:
    # 1 > POST https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
    # 1 > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    # 1 > Content-Length: 9
    # 1 > Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
    # 1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
    # 1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.7)
    # 1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    # user=test
```

https://github.com/aleruz/karate-call-single-bug/blob/main/src/test/java/examples/users/create-user-post-form.feature

Reproduce running

`mvn test "-Dkarate.options=--tags @create-user-post"`

Comment: this time I'm going to insist on a way to replicate as I've no idea what you're talking about. and this request goes to the very very end of the queue since we've been asking users to provide feedback on the RC-s for **MONTHS**

Comment: I did edit the question adding better info and a link to the repo used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I was not complaining, just asking if I was doing something wrong. I am sorry I could not try the RC, but hope feedback is still valid. If you give me some hints on the part of the code which could cause this, I could also try to have a look and submit a PR.